# Upgrading from very old firmware on HPE ProLiant DL380e Gen8 Server - can I upgrade it to the newest version right away?

Tags: hp-proliant, firmware-update

I'm trying to upgrade firmware on a HPE ProLiant DL380e Gen8 Server. The current version is 1.22 Apr 19 2013, while the newest version available on HP's website is 2.80 (April 8 2022). Is it safe to upgrade it straight to the newest version or should I do it incrementally?

Comment: What were your findings? Did the update work? I The automatic update fails here (not same but similar setup) https://serverfault.com/questions/1126922/broken-signature-prevents-update-of-the-firmware-on-hpe-gen10

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The firmware updates supersede each other, so you should be able to go straight to the newest revision. This assumes you have access to the download from the HPE site.

Good luck!