# Broken Signature Prevents Update of the Firmware on HPE Gen10

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo, hpe, digital-signatures, firmware-update

A HPE Gen10 server could not update from ILO 5 version 2.10 to the current one.
I tried the ILO webinterface and the local update function.

The signature was not correct. Even after manually downloading the .bin file the signature was not accepted by the server.

I found a hint to download the SuSE RPM installer, extract the files and upload `ilo5_278.bin` from there via webinterface.
This worked finally and the server runs ILO 5, 2.78 now.
Next I want to update the other tools.

The Server found new versions online:

[image: The HP Gen10 Server found new versions online]

All services are marked for Update:
[image: All services are marked for Update]

One or more firmware updates failed:
[image: One or more firmware updates failed]

Details about the environment/system:

```
Product Name            ProLiant MicroServer Gen10 Plus
System ROM              U48 v2.10 (03/09/2020)
System ROM Date         03/09/2020
Redundant System ROM    U48 v2.10 (03/09/2020)
Product ID              P16006-421

All systems here are running Linux 
The first LAN port is connected to the internet
An ILO card is built in and also in use
```

**How can I get the updates working again?**

Answer (score -1):

If the firmware update for the HPE Gen10 server is failing due to a broken signature, it is possible that the firmware file you downloaded is corrupt, or there is an issue with the firmware signature verification process on the server.

Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

- Verify the firmware file: Try downloading the firmware file again from the HPE website and verify its checksum to ensure that it has not been corrupted during the download process.
- Check the firmware signature: Check the firmware signature on the HPE website to ensure that it matches the signature on the firmware file you downloaded. If the signatures do not match, then the file you downloaded may have been tampered with or corrupted.
- Disable Secure Boot: If the firmware file is correct and the signature is valid, it is possible that the server's Secure Boot feature is preventing the firmware update from being installed. Try disabling the Secure Boot feature and then attempt the firmware update again. Also, you can find [this page](https://hpe.to/6609OBT6U) helpful as well.